# sudo apt-get update and ownCloud

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, updates, owncloud

I have an **issue when i try to update with linux command**, everything goes well until this error :

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.04/packages/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:2178:8::13 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_14.04/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:2178:8::13 80]

I uninstalled ownCLound using this command :

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove owncloud
```

but when i redo the update i still have the same error,

can you please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you indicate how you added those repo ? It seems your second link is broken because you added a `x` in the url  `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/`x`Ubuntu_14.04/Packages`.

Comment: Hi, i did not add these repositories, they are called automatically when i do sudo apt-get update, but if you have any way to change these repositories dont hesitate

Comment: Are you trying to install owncloud ?
If not go in your /etc/apt/source.list and /etc/apt/source.list.d then remove lines containing those url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this issue you have to go to

System Settings->Software & Updates -> other software, then uncheck the ones that causes trouble.

In this case, you have to uncheck all the links related to ownCloud and magic happens